# Autohotkey script - hotstring prevents if statement from working

Tags: if-statement, autohotkey

```
:*:pl::pleaseHelpMe     ; hotstring

:*:rf::reallyConfused   ; hotstring

toggle := 0
\::
if (toggle = 0)
{
Run "https://www.google.com.sg/"
}
return
```

The code above does not work for the keystroke '\'

However, the code below works without the hotstrings

```
toggle := 0
\::
if (toggle = 0)
{
Run "https://www.google.com.sg/"
}
return
```

Why is that so? And how do I circumvent it and have the use of my hotstrings and the keystroke '\' to open google. Thanks a billion!!

Comment: Why do you have to use hotstrings? They don't seem to do anything useful.

Comment: Hotstrings terminate the automatic execution of code lines, see [auto-execute section](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#auto). `toggle := 0` is never executed and therewith `toggle = 0` never becomes true. Put everything you want to be executed at script start before the first hotkey/hotstring/subroutine.

Comment: @2501, my script is actually much longer; I just isolated the parts that are problematic. As you can see, these are just examples; I do not want to put :*:pwd::ofCourseIWldNotWantToPutMyRealPwdDown :))

Comment: @Neo Ding Yue please consider changing your selected answer, you were given false information, look at my answer and decide which is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot define a **variable** between hotkeys or hotstrings.

A variable has to be defined

- in the auto executable section of the script (top of the script,
  before the first return or hotkey),
- or in a hotkey,
- or in a function.

**Example:**

```
; top of the script:
toggle := 0
    return      ; end of auto-execute section

; toggling a variable:
F1:: toggle := !toggle  ; Pressing F1 changes the value of the variable "toggle" between 1 (true) and 0 (false)

:*:pl::pleaseHelpMe     ; hotstring
:*:rf::reallyConfused   ; hotstring

\::
if (toggle) ; If the value of the variable "toggle" is 1 (true)
    Run "https://www.google.com.sg/"
else
    Send, \
return
```

Comment: The answer isn't wrong. If you don't define a **default** value  of the variable in the auto executable section you're getting a warning of missing a global declaration.

Comment: With #Warn enabled you will see this message. Consider editing your post to clarify this? Without #Warn, the code executes and performs with no issues, in fact I've never seen any ill affect from performing a Bool operation or even incremental operations from a non declared global or local variable, but I don't use #warn in my scripts, so this is not an issue in the op's code, unless you make it so with having Warnings enabled.

Comment: As far as I know: **#Warn is recommended** for catching common errors. It also  distinguishes between variables which have been initialized by the script and variables which have not. In this case there's no error message there, just a warning. If you get this warning ("This variable has not been assigned a value"), the answer is obviously to assign a value to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

user3419297 is wrong. AutoHotkey does not need to define a variable prior to it's use. If a variable isn't defined it is automatically given a value of False or 0 during an evaluation.

This code works, I only added $ option to the hotkey to prevent the hotkey from triggering itself:

```
; toggling a variable:
F1:: toggle := !toggle  ; Pressing F1 changes the value of the variable "toggle" between 1 (true) and 0 (false)

:*:pl::pleaseHelpMe     ; hotstring
:*:rf::reallyConfused   ; hotstring

$\::
if (toggle) ; If the value of the variable "toggle" is 1 (true)
    Run "https://www.google.com.sg/"
else
    Send, \
return

esc::exitApp
```

Comment: It isn't wrong to define the **default** value of the variable in the auto executable section.

Comment: It's not correct, sorry but the interpreter doesn't require it for its use in an evalution of true or fslse. You are wrong, your answer is wrong. The only thing wrong with his code was the lack a $ option to diable send from triggering the hotkey.